# Will I get pulled over for driving a car in Washington if I bought the a brand new car in Oregon with no license plate?

Tags: licensing, traffic, license-plates

I just bought a brand new car from a dealership that was located in Oregon and currently have to wait 2 weeks for the license plates for some reason. I will be driving the car in Washington state. The Oregon DMV stated that there is a very low chance that a police officer would pull me over for lacking plates. Does that sound correct?  If so, would I just be able to provide proof of sale, insurance, etc. and show them the details?

I do have a temporary Oregon license plate.

Comment: @user3864563 have you created two accounts accidentally? http://law.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: You've stated you have "no license plate" then you stated you do have a "temporary license plate" .. if you have one then you're fine.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you comply with Oregon laws regarding the display of the temporary registration/tag (as well as the state's other laws regarding insurance and documentation you must have when operating the vehicle on public roads) then you cannot be found guilty of operating an unregistered vehicle or improper documentation in Washington.

*In theory* police in any state can pull you over for anything they think looks questionable.  They can even, in theory, write you citations for violations of which you are not guilty.  But when you present compelling evidence to whatever court they charge you in that you are *not* guilty then you should expect to be absolved of guilt.

*In practice* police are familiar with temporary tags and new cars, especially for neighboring states.  If they had any question they would run the temporary plate to confirm it is valid, that you are compliant with your state's laws, and send you on your way.